# How do I solve a multi-digit number manipulation problem in Python

Tags: python, loops, math, numbers, digits

I am required to solve the following using only python code: There are two 3-digit numbers    having the property that    is divisible by 11 and  /11  is equal to the sum of the squares of the digits of   .

Find both values of   .

I understand that I need to plug in 1-9 for the first digit, 0-9 for the second and third until I get a combination of digits who's squares sum up to n/11, and also n/11 needs to be a whole number with no remainder. I know I will need to use loops, but I am really stuck on how to check every possible three digit number to see if it meets the conditions.

Comment: `for i in range(100, 1000): check_conditions(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
for num in range(110,1000,11) :
    digits = map( int, str(num) )
    if sum([i*i for i in digits]) * 11 == num :
        print num
```

---

Answering to comments:

`range(110, 1000, 11)` iterates over the three-digit numbers that are multiple of 11, the first being 110 = (11 * 10), next 121 = (11 * 11) and so on.

`digits = map( int, str(num) )` converts a number into a string using `str(num)`, then takes every digit and using `int` to convert it back to integer. If you had `num = 534`, this would result in a list `[5, 3, 4]`. You may get similar results by using `[int(i) for i in str(num)]`, but this is longer and less elegant, IMHO.

Comment: Why not to start the loop from 110?

Comment: `n` is a three digit number. `n/11` can be smaller than 3 digits. And since you are iterating over the possibilities for `n/11` rather than `n` starting at 110 doesn't seem right.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk 1) `num` is a three digit number 2) from which number would you like to start iterating??

Comment: Ah, ok, got it!

Comment: Thank you so much for  the answer! It worked and helped a lot. Do you think you could explain everything you do here fully? I'm really glad you helped but I would like to understand myself what you did here. From what I understand, the bottom two lines are the ones that check if n/11 is the sum of the squares of the digits, but I am not sure about the first two lines and why you used that specific range. Please help!

Comment: @ParadoxBlu updated the answer, please check it out.